# Github pages for Github project

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am new to Github pages. I followed their instructions for [User, Organization, and Project Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) and [Creating Project Pages manually](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/),
so I have something up at [oresoftware.github.io](http://oresoftware.github.io), which is my Github "user site".

Now I am looking to put something up at oresoftware.github.io/suman, a "project site".

The problem, and this might be telling, is that

[oresoftware.github.io/suman/index.html](http://oresoftware.github.io/suman/index.html) is available

but I get a `404` when going to

[oresoftware.github.io/suman](http://oresoftware.github.io/suman)

there is probably a good reason for that, but I am not that knowledgeable with the www.

Why would this be? The project structure for my github repo (gh-pages branch) might give info about why - https://github.com/ORESoftware/suman/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Ok, for some reason the site, without index.html appended, is now working, so my question is now, what should my project structure be if I am using jsdoc, and my "out" folder is a simple subdirectory from the root of the project?

Comment: It looks like it's working now (http://oresoftware.github.io/suman/ shows some content). Do you have some another issue?

Comment: thanks, my only other question at the moment is how to integrate jsdoc with github.io...with the index.html file needing to be at the root of your project, this doesn't jive with how jsdoc "out" directories work

Comment: the easiest thing to solve this problem would be to configure github.io to read the index.html from a different directory other than root

Answer (score 1):

As of today's date, your repo https://github.com/ORESoftware/suman has no `gh-pages` branch

a `gh-pages` branch is required for Github Pages